# Overload operator '+' for generic

Tags: c#, events, operator-overloading

I have a class `ListenableValue<T>` that fires an event when the value is modified.

```cs
public class ListenableValue<T>
{
    public delegate void OnChanged(T newValue);

    public event OnChanged onChanged;
    private T m_value;

    public static implicit operator T(ListenableValue<T> value) => value.m_value;

    public T value
    {
        get
        {
            return m_value;
        }

        set
        {
            m_value = value;
            onChanged(m_value);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to support this:

```cs
ListenableValue<int> myValue = new ListenableValue<int>;
myValue += 3;

// Now myValue.m_value == 3
```

And this does not compile :

```cs
    public static ListenableValue<T> operator +(ListenableValue<T> lhs, T rhs)
    {
        ListenableValue<T> copy = new ListenableValue<T>();
        copy.onChanged = lhs.onChanged;
        copy.m_value = lhs.m_value + rhs;
        return copy;
    }
```

I am also concerned about these things :

1. Performance-wise, is `copy.onChanged = lhs.onChanged;` costly?
2. The returned object is a new object with the same event handler reference. The two objects are now linked. It would be better to deep copy the listeners. But the best would be to disallow completly `+`.

Comment: += is implicitly overloaded by the + operator. Your onChanged event handler registration is not related to the += operator on the type itself. `myValue.onChanged += something` is a different += operator than `myValue += 3`.

Comment: += can’t be overloaded, but What are you expecting from overloading += in your scenario?

Comment: I don't get the idea of what you are trying to achieve here. Variables/fields/properties can have different values (assigned), so _their_ values can change. So, if you know that "something" got a new value that differs from the previous value it had, how do you know where and what that "something" is? Do you really want to have a separate event handler for every ListenableValue instance to keep track of which "something" precisely has changed?  Or asked differently, why are you not going down the INotifyPropertyChanged route?

Comment: Disclaimer : I am a C# beginner. Yes, I have a separate event handler for each instance but if needed one day I could juste add an argument `object sender` to the delegate like the microsoft example on events. I didn't knew about INotifyPropertyChanged so i'll investigate this.